# ios - set gradient with custom colors

Tags: ios, view, colors, gradient

I am trying to set gradient on my main View with custom colors. View is displayed completely white though. What's wrong with this record?

```
 CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer new];

 gradient.colors = @[(id)[UIColor colorWithRed:92.0 green:196.0 blue:244.0 alpha:1].CGColor,
                    (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:47.0 green:146.0 blue:229.0 alpha:1].CGColor];
gradient.frame = self.backGroundView.bounds;
gradient.locations = @[@0.5, @0.5];

[self.backGroundView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

This is properly displayed with blue and red cut in half of view's height.

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer new];
gradient.colors = @[(id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor];
gradient.frame = self.backGroundView.bounds;
gradient.locations = @[@0.5, @0.5];

[self.backGroundView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your colors are wrong. the `UIColor` initializer expects values between 0 and 1. try this:

```
gradient.colors = @[(id)[UIColor colorWithRed:92/255.0 green:196/255.0 blue:244/255.0 alpha:1].CGColor,
                    (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:47/255.0 green:146/255.0 blue:229/255.0 alpha:1].CGColor];
```